# Deleting rows on dbf table with python for ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, table, dbf

Being not very familiar with python, and after carrying out unfruitful long research on internet, I submit to you my problem, hoping favorable reply.

I have a DBF table with geochemical data and I would like writing a script to be integrated in a wider model built with ModelBuilder, and that automatically delete some specific rows, specifically (please see attached example) the rows 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6, while the row 3 (Analyte symbol) is maintained. This is first.

Secondly, I would like to automatically fill in some empty cells in some coloumns (e.g., A, B, C) with the character 0 (zero). Could you please show me the way?

[image: Example]

---

In fact, by deleting rows 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6, I want the row 3 to become the first row (headline) of the table (i.e., Au, Pt, pd, SiO2...). The latter contains 150 rows of data below the 6 first rows, that begins with #59101 in the provided example.

Thus, I do not want to keep just the row 3, but really deleting the rows 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6, so that the row 3 becomes the headline of 150 rows of data (as shown in the herein attached example).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract just row 3 and want to keep using ModelBuilder then you'll be wanting something like this:

1. Create a model with your DBF as one of the inputs
2. Use the **[Make Query Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Query_Table/00170000006r000000/)** tool or the **[Select Layer By Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000)** tool with the query `"\"COLUMN_A\" = 'Analyte Symbol'"` (Substitute the real attribute name for `COLUMN_A`)
3. Optional: Use **Copy Rows** to create a new DBF file with only the line you want in it
4. Feed that table into **[Iterate Field Values](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Field_Values/00400000000t000000/)**
5. Feed each field into **[Get Field Value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000006000000)**
6. Feed the table into **[Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000)** with the Field Value as a prerequisite, using a function something like:

   `if FieldValue is not None:
     return FieldValue
   else:
     return 0`

That should leave you with a table of just the Analyte Symbols and 0's in the blank spaces.